# Understanding notation for binary relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Determine whether or not following relation is reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric and transitive. $A$ is an arbitrary set:

$$R=\left\{(x,y)\in{\bigl(\mathscr P(A)\bigr)}^2\mid x\cap y\neq\emptyset\right\}.$$

I am having trouble understanding the notation here. The condition to check reflexivity is to check that for all elements $x$ in $A$, $(x,x)$ is in $R$. But I am confused about how an element in the Cartesian product of the powerset of $A$ could have the form $(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are elements of $A$.

Basically I am looking for an English translation of the statement 
$R=\left\{(x,y)\in{\bigl(\mathscr P(A)\bigr)}^2\mid x\cap y\neq\emptyset\right\}$. What exactly is this statement saying about the properties of $R$?

Comment: $R$ is a relation on $\mathscr{P}(A)$ - so for example, to check whether reflexivity is true, you need to see whether $(x, x) \in R$ for each $x \in \mathscr{P}(A)$, not for each $x \in A$.

Comment: How does one know which set the relation is on?

Comment: @user140161: When $R=\{ (x,y)\in B^2 \mid \,\cdots\,\}$, then $R$ is a relation on $B$. Here $B$ happens to be $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: what if it was $B^7$? What would R be on then?

Comment: You couldn't have B^7, because a relation is between pairs of things and B^7 is a set of septuplets.

Comment: @ConMan: Of course you could split $B^7$ into e.g. $B^3\times B^4$ and consider that as a relation between triples and quadruples. Of course that split is not unique, so the relation would not be well defined unless it is exactly specified how to split (which you'd exactly do by writing $B^3\times B^4$ instead of $B^7$ if you mean the 3-4 split). And of course the resulting relation is necessarily between different sets and thus could not possibly be an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation $R$ says that $x \sim y$ (i.e. $x$ is related to $y$), where $(x,y) \in P(A) \times P(A)$, if $x \cap y \neq \emptyset$.

Here, by definition, $x$ and $y$ are elements of $(P(A))^2$ (i.e. $P(A) \times P(A)$).

In order to check reflexivity, for example, you would check that $x \sim x$, for $x \in P(A)$.

I.e. check that $(x,x) \in R$. This is clear, though, because $(x,x) \in (P(A))^2$, and $x \cap x \neq \emptyset$. By definition of $R$, we have indeed that $(x,x) \in R$.

Comment: P(A) would also contain ∅ as element. And ∅∩∅= ∅. Does that not mean R is NOT reflexive?

Comment: Looks true to me, well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

$R= \{ (x,y) \in P^2(A) : x \cap y \ne  \emptyset \}$

$(x,y) \in P^2(A)$ means that $x$ and $y$ are subsets of $A$. Hence $xRy$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ have at least one point in common.

At the urging of @HenningMarkholm, 
$\mathcal{P}^2(A) = (\mathcal{P}(A))^2 =\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(A) $ where $\mathcal{P}(A)$, the power set of $A$, is the set of all subsets of $A$. So $(x,y) \in \mathcal{P}^2(A)$ means that $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and 
$y \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. In other words, $x$ and $y$ are subsets of $A$.

Comment: I doubt that writing $(\mathcal P(A))^2$ as $P^2(A)$ is going to clarify anything for someone who needs to ask this question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Then it's a good thing that's not why I did it.